# how to get a lines of text that is between to known texts in a file to excel with delimiters in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am very new to vb 2010 programming

i am able to open a text file and copy the entire file to excel sheet

but i want to copy only some part of the text file to excel file
how to do please guide me

for example

i have a text file with a lot of data

some data
........
........
.......
......

### JOINT COORDINATES

COORDINATES ARE METE UNIT

JOINT X Y Z

1 0.000 0.000 5.203

2 0.000 0.000 9.015

3 0.000 0.000 12.933

4 0.000 0.000 14.363

5 0.000 0.000 19.740

6 0.000 0.000 25.120

..................

........................................

.....................

960 21.966 12.400 5.203

961 17.505 12.400 5.203

962 34.107 12.400 14.360

963 28.735 12.400 14.360

964 21.966 12.400 14.360

965 17.505 12.400 14.360

966 12.132 12.400 14.360

************ END OF DATA FROM INTERNAL STORAGE ************

..................

.....................

some data

..................

................

...................

i want to extract data only the rows starting from 1 to 966 and paste in a excel sheet  at a particular cells. ie take the first row is 1 0.000 0.000 5.203
my output in excel is A1 =1, B1= 0.000, C1= 0.000, D1=5.203

the same output i got in **excel vba** but i require it in vb 2010

please guide me

gvg

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38ff268f-3c9d-4151-8c8f-6673743462ca/writing-from-text-file-to-excel-file?forum=csharpgeneral

see if it helps

Comment: i think the reffered answer regarding to C# not vb.net